# Connect a new hardware(RF card reader) to android device

Tags: android, android-hardware

I am trying to understand one concept in android devices that is, connecting a new hardware to an android device.
How is ir achievable. without bluetooth.
suppose I have one RF card reader and I want to read RF id cards using that hardware and i want to show that number(RF ID) to my
Activity. how is it achievable??
  If its possible then how? Do we have to install drivers for it??

Any kind of help will be appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Square card reader - it is plugged into the microphone jack - no drivers are required.